# Use MongoDB TimeSeries collection to store daily data?

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking to store historical daily average spot price of several cryptocurrencies in MongoDB.  I've used Mongo in the past, but was recently introduced to TimeSeries collections, which feel like it would make sense here.  However, one of the parameters when creating a TimeSeries collection is `granularity`, the options being `seconds`, `minutes`, and `hours`. **Given that I'm only looking to store on the day level is this even the right approach**? Case studies seem to indicate that Mongo can more easily compress the data and read it more quickly, but is this really overkill in my case.  Secondly, a case study indicates the usefulness of bucketing TimeSeries data and I can see how that could be useful here:

A singular document for each coin could look like:

```
{
  _id: ....,
  date: ISODate(),
  price: 100,
  symbol: 'btc'
}

{
  _id: ....,
  date: ISODate(),
  price: 120,
  symbol: 'eth'
}
```

A quasi-bucketed approach could combine them:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  date: ISODate(),
  prices: [
    {
      symbol: 'btc',
      price: 100
    },
    {
      symbol: 'eth',
      price: 120
    }
  }
}
```

With my limited introduction to TimeSeries databases, is it the correct choice, and does my schema look decent?

Comment: The first one is going to do you better into the future. I would say, generally, you want to match your data to the way you are piping it in. So, if you are recording instances of a coin price at a given time, record it that way in your database. As an aside, I'm not sure if it's still this way, but last year Mongo's built in TimeBucketing was really slow compared to arithmetic approaches. I'd watch out for this either way you go.

Comment: What did you end up with?

Answer (score 0):

As @Imonninger said your first approach is better. It will allow for easier querying.

Given you are looking at daily data in the crypto space you are not likely to have a large timeseries going back in time so the Timeseries approach might be overkill. I think the Timeseries collection is better suited for intra-day or higher-frequency applications where you are willing to trade off some functionality of a regular collection with an optimised collection. For example, if you have bad data in your database and are using MongoDB 5.0 or lower you will have [restrictions on updating and deleting records](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-limitations/#updates-and-deletes)

For your case: given that crypto data has many sources, trades on different exchanges with varying levels of liquidity, trades 24/7 (ie there is no "closing price"), and traded against different currencies or coins, you might find the following schema useful. Additionally I have included `'date'` in a string format as this can be easier to lookup or work with than an `ISODate()` object

```
{
  _id: ....,
  dateUploaded: ISODate(),
  source: Foo
  exchange: Bar
  price: 120,
  dateFull:ISODate(),
  date: "YYYY-MM-DD"
  baseCurrency: 'eth'
  quoteCurrency: 'usdt'
}
```